# Play ! Framework 2.1 cannot download Mailer Plugin

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

When building my Play! 2.1 application it's not downloading the Mailer Plugin;

> [  com.typesafe#play-plugins-mailer_2.10;2.0.4: not found  ]

I followed all the steps from this Readme : https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/mailer !

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I advise to use this dependency with Play 2.1.0

```
"com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.1.0"
```

Answer (score -3):

Instead of `play-plugin-mailer` dependency, which is mentioned in `github` link, add the following dependency to your build.scala file:

```
 "com.typesafe" % "play-plugins-mailer_2.9.1" % "2.0.4"
```

Next:

- add `1500:com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin` to your `conf/play.plugins`
- add `"import com.typesafe.plugin.*;"` to the class you are going to send mail from.

Comment: The Scala 2.10.0 version of this dependency should be used with Play 2.1.